# Is my understanding of parallel operations in Spark correct?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie to Spark and trying to understand the Spark concept with Python. While using Python to develop applications for Spark, I get a bit confused with the way to get my data processed in parallel style.

**1**. Everyone says that I don't need to worry about which node and how many nodes will be invloved in processing my data encapsulated in RDD variables. Therefore, based on my best understanding, I believe what a Spark cluster would do to the code below:

```
a = sc.textFile(filename)
b = a.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and x.split("\t").count("9999-12-31") == 0)
c = b.collect()
```

could be described as the following steps:

**(1)** Variable `a` will be saved as an RDD variable containing the    expected txt file content 
**(2)** Different chunks of RDD `a` will be broadcasted to different nodes in the cluster and filter method will be conducted for each chunk in different node
 **(3)** when the collection action is invoked, the results will be returned to the master from different nodes and saved as a local variable, `c`.

Is my description right? If not, what exactly will the procedure be? If I am right, what is the point to have parallelize method? Does the following code experience the same thing as that listed above?

```
a = sc.textFile(filename).collect()
b = sc.parallelize(a).filter(lambda x: len(x)>0 and x.split("\t").count("9999-12-31"))
c = b.collect()
```

**2**. For the following code, would the SQL query syntax be processed in parallel by dividing the defined table into many partitions?

```
a = sc.textFile(filename)
b = a.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and x.split("\t").count("9999-12-31") == 0)
parts = b.map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
records = parts.map(Row(r0 = str(x[0]), r1 = x[1], r2 = x[2]))
rTable = sqlContext.createDataFrame(records)
rTable.registerTempTable("rTable")
result = sqlContext.sql("select substr(r0,1,2), case when r1=1 then r1*100 else r1*10 end, r2 from rTable").collect()
```

Comment: That code seems rather incorrect for starter.

Comment: could you possibly give me more hint please? thanks

Comment: Did you try to run your code at least?

Comment: These codes are pasted from my test program. Anyway, I just tested them again and they are all working. by the way, I did not give the delcaration of sqlContext here which have been defined via syntax sqlContext=SQLContext(sc).

Comment: As far as I know, the `sc.textFile` method automatically parallelize your data, so no need to call `parallelize` in this case. You use the `parallelize` method when you want to parallelize something that isn't already parallelized, like a normal List or a Set for instance.

Comment: thanks for your help! do you know if the sqlContext.sql() is by default proceeded in parallel? Great Thanks again!

Comment: Parallelized collections are created by calling SparkContext’s parallelize method on an existing Collection in your driver program. The elements of the collection are copied to form a distributed dataset that can be operated on in parallel. So use parallelize when you need parallelized collections in Driver Program https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/spark-parallelize-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step description is true. But there is something more about second and third steps.

#### Second Step:

According to Spark documentation:

> def textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String]
>
> The textFile method also takes an optional second argument for controlling the number of partitions of the file. By default, Spark creates one partition for each block of the file (blocks being 64MB by default in HDFS), but you can also ask for a higher number of partitions by passing a larger value.

If you put your file in HDFS and pass its path as `textFile` parameter, partitions of RDD `a` are created based on the HDFS blocks. So in this case the amount of palatalization  depend on number of HDFS blocks. Also data has already partitioned and moved to cluster machines via HDFS.

If you use path on the local file system (available on all nodes) and do not specify `minPartitions` the default parallelism (that depends on number of cores in your cluster) is chosen. In this case you have to copy your file on every worker or put it into a shared storage which is available to every worker.

In each of the cases, Spark avoid broadcasting any data and instead tries to use existing blocks in each machines. So your second step is not totally true.

#### Third Step

According to Spark documentation:

> collect(): Array[T]
>   Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD

In this step your RDD `b` is shuffled/collected into your driver program/node.

Comment: Thanks for your help! do you know if the sqlContext.sql() is by default proceeded in parallel? Great Thanks again!